# How to avoid sentence segmentation from conjunction in spacy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am using spacy for text mining for one of my project. Is there any way to avoid sentence segmentation from Coordinating Conjunction(and , or, yet etc..) without using custom segmentation.

```
document = "I love swimming and i love playing badminton too"
doc = nlp(document)
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent)
```

> Output:

```
I love swimming 
and i love playing badminton too
```

> Expected output:

```
I love swimming and i love playing badminton too
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading spacy didn't solve it in my case and I had troubles with creating a new virtual environment, but this worked for me: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#component-example1

In your case:

```
import spacy

def custom_sentencizer(doc):
    for i, token in enumerate(doc[:-2]):
        # Define sentence start if pipe + titlecase token
        if token.text in [".", "!", "?"] and doc[i+1].is_title:
            doc[i+1].is_sent_start = True
        else:
            # Explicitly set sentence start to False otherwise, to tell
            # the parser to leave those tokens alone
            doc[i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.add_pipe(custom_sentencizer, before="parser")  # Insert before the parser

document = "I love swimming and i love playing badminton too. I love swimming and i love playing badminton too! I love swimming and i love playing badminton too."
doc = nlp(document)
for sent in doc.sents:
    print(sent,'\n')
```

> Output:
>
> I love swimming and i love playing badminton too.
>
> I love swimming and i love playing badminton too!
>
> I love swimming and i love playing badminton too.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to `spaCy 2.3.0` and `en_core_web_sm 2.3.0`. The latest version's of spaCy are not stable.

```sh
pip install spacy==2.3.0
python -m spacy downoad en_core_web_sm
```

If you already have spaCy installed in your virtual environment, then you should delete and create a new virtual environment as spaCy come with a lot of dependencies, and it is not easy to zero down on what is causing the issue.

Comment: Currently using the stable version 2.3.0
spacy                      2.3.0
SQLAlchemy                 1.3.11
sqlparse                   0.3.0
srsly                      1.0.2
sympy                      1.4
tabula-py                  2.1.0
tabulate                   0.8.6
tensor2tensor              1.14.1
tensorboard                1.15.0
tensorflow                 1.15.0
tensorflow-datasets        1.3.0
tensorflow-estimator       1.15.1
tensorflow-gan             2.0.0
tensorflow-hub             0.7.0
tensorflow-metadata        0.15.1
tensorflow-probability     0.7.0